# swift 4 / firebase Super Simple read / write. Can't read

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Super newbie!  I just want to practice reading and writing for Firebase.  My write code works!  I've consulted dozens of examples online and still can't get the read portion working.

As a newbie, I've also tried some simple debug techniques but no help.
Exactly how do I fix this code so that the read happens (and I know it happened because the code prints to terminal)?

I'd really like a Swift 4 based solution, thanks.

[My repo](https://github.com/bbookman/helpMeFirebase)

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var ref:DatabaseReference!
    var refHandle:DatabaseHandle!
    ref = Database.database().reference()
    ref.child("test").setValue("name: Bruce")
```

//Nothing below works

```
    refHandle = ref.child("test").observe(DataEventType.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
        let info = snapshot.value as? String
        print(info as Any)
    })

}
```

Note that my Firebase DB is enabled for READ and WRITE.  I have also tried observeSingleInsance (or whatever it is when you read just once).

I know the write works because i can see the data in the Firebase console

Comment: Make sure that read is public or you're using auth properly... Code looks fine to me. Maybe you should try other events i.e. value... let me know if it doesn't work. will try to help.

Comment: You don't have to "auth" right?  I can write the data with zero "auth"

Comment: You mentioned your write works fine. Did you check it in firebase console as well if the data is written...

Comment: Yes, that is how i know the write is a success

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your problem is in setValue("name: Bruce"), where you set the node "test" to "name: Bruce", as opposed to "name": "Bruce"
if you change that to say

```
updateChildValues(["name": "Bruce"])
```

surely it would work.

Answer (score 0):

Read like that as you currently trying to listen to child add , so replace childAdded with value , Also you should wait until write process happens and then read , suppose launch app again for read only

```
  refHandle = ref.child("test").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
    let info = snapshot.value as? String
    print(info as Any)
})
```

Comment: The observe continually runs, so it makes no sense to 'wait until write'.  I have tried the same code with the data already in place with the same non-results.  I will try your suggestion, but I think I remember doing it and having no success.

Comment: Changing to .value did not change the results - which are none

Answer (score 0):

Go to your Firebase console, and perform following steps which is identify in image.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do you have this enabled? Then try changing it to

```
Database.database().isPersistenceEnabled = false
```

Otherwise try this and print the snapshot you get (You don't actually need the handle):

```
ref.child("test").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
    print(snapshot)
})
```

Comment: Don't need the handle?  Can you elaborate?  In every example I have seen of the read/write code, the handle is used https://iosrevisited.blogspot.com/2017/10/firebase-realtime-database-example-ios-swift.html

Comment: The handle is used to remove the observer. It is true, you should always remove the observers when you don't need them anymore, but since you are only testing now, it is best to remove 'noise'. :)